# Changing the scale of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Sorry if I messed up the title, I didn't know how to phrase this. Anyways, I have a tensor of a set of values, but I want to make sure that every element in the tensor has a range from 0 - 255, (or 0 - 1 works too). However, I don't want to make all the values add up to 1 or 255 like softmax, I just want to down scale the values.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are trying to normalize the data. A classic normalization formula is this one:

```
normalize_value = (value − min_value) / (max_value − min_value)
```

The implementation on tensorflow will look like this:

```
tensor = tf.div(
   tf.subtract(
      tensor, 
      tf.reduce_min(tensor)
   ), 
   tf.subtract(
      tf.reduce_max(tensor), 
      tf.reduce_min(tensor)
   )
)
```

All the values of the tensor will be betweetn 0 and 1.

**IMPORTANT**: make sure the tensor has float/double values, or the output tensor will have just zeros and ones. If you have a integer tensor call this first:

```
tensor = tf.to_float(tensor)
```

**Update**: as of tensorflow 2, `tf.to_float()` is deprecated and instead, `tf.cast()` should be used:

```
tensor = tf.cast(tensor, dtype=tf.float32) # or any other tf.dtype, that is precise enough
```

Comment: Also make sure to take the maximum of a small value (i.e. epsilon=1e-12) and the denominator to avoid div by zero. `(val - min_val) / max((max_val - min_val), epsilon)`

Comment: And add epsilon to the numerator, 2*epsilon to the denominator to result in 0.5 when val==max==min `(val - min_val + epsilon) / max((max_val - min_val), 2*epsilon)`

Comment: However if your training data has max pixel 254 and the test or reald data has 255 the norm would be off (hopefully nothing would change much anyways.)  Then for images you may just use the max and min values from your knowledge imho.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) in Wikipedia you can also try the Scaling to unit length:

[image]

It can be implemented using this segment of code:

```
In [3]: a = tf.constant([2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 1.0, 0])                                                                                                                                                                     
In [4]: b = a / tf.norm(a)
In [5]: b.eval()
Out[5]: array([ 0.26490647,  0.52981293,  0.79471946,  0.13245323,  0.        ], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Just adding that this implementation of the norm is known as the L2 norm. It's calculated as the square root of the sum of the squared vector values.

Answer (score 5):

`sigmoid(tensor) * 255` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Let the input be

```
X = tf.constant([[0.65,0.61, 0.59, 0.62, 0.6 ],[0.25,0.31, 0.89, 0.52, 0.6 ]])
```

We can define a scaling function

```
def rescale(X, a=0, b=1):
  repeat = X.shape[1]
  xmin = tf.repeat(tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_min(X, axis=1), shape=[-1,1]), repeats=repeat, axis=1)
  xmax = tf.repeat(tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_max(X, axis=1), shape=[-1,1]), repeats=repeat, axis=1)
  X = (X - xmin) / (xmax-xmin)
  return X * (b - a) + a
```

This outputs  X in range [0,1]

```
>>rescale(X)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1.        , 0.333334  , 0.        , 0.5000005 , 0.16666749],
       [0.        , 0.09375001, 1.        , 0.42187497, 0.54687506]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

To scale in range [0, 255]

```
>> rescale(X, 0, 255) 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[255.      ,  85.00017 ,   0.      , 127.50012 ,  42.50021 ],
       [  0.      ,  23.906252, 255.      , 107.57812 , 139.45314 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, you need to normalize each image separately - for example adversarial datasets where each image has noise. The following normalizes each image according to its own min and max, assuming the inputs have typical size Batch x YDim x XDim x Channels:

```
    cast_input = tf.cast(inputs,dtype=tf.float32)     # e.g. MNIST is integer
    input_min = tf.reduce_min(cast_input,axis=[1,2])  # result B x C
    input_max = tf.reduce_max(cast_input,axis=[1,2])
    ex_min = tf.expand_dims(input_min,axis=1)         #  put back inner dimensions
    ex_max = tf.expand_dims(input_max,axis=1)
    ex_min = tf.expand_dims(ex_min,axis=1)            # one at a time - better way?
    ex_max = tf.expand_dims(ex_max,axis=1)            # Now Bx1x1xC
    input_range = tf.subtract(ex_max, ex_min)
    floored = tf.subtract(cast_input,ex_min)          # broadcast
    scale_input = tf.divide(floored,input_range)
```

I would like to expand the dimensions in one short like you can in Numpy, but tf.expand_dims seems to only accept one dimension at a a time - open to suggestions here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum value to be the effective upper bound of the 0-1 range and there's a meaningful zero then using this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tensor = tf.constant([0, 1, 5, 10])
tensor = tf.divide(tensor, tf.reduce_max(tensor))
tf.print(tensor)
```

would result in:

```
[0 0.1 0.5 1]
```