# Normalize numpy ndArray

Tags: python, time-series, normalization, scaling, numpy-ndarray

Hey iam facing the Problem of normalizing (0...1) my dataset,

my timeseries dataset is of shape:
`(batch_size, observations, num_sensors)`

So having batches of timeseries of length `observations` for `num_sensors` different Sensors (corresponds to num_Feature).

The Problem with this `ndArray` is that i cannot apply e.g. scikit Scalers as they expect Arrays of only 2 dims.

Can anyone please give me a Hint on how i can normalize the timeseries to values between 0...1 without iterating through the ndArray using a for loop?

**EDIT:** I finally found a solution here which does what im looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38377600/6639994

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. What is your expected input and output? What does normalization of the values of the array have to do with reshaping the array?

Answer (score 0):

To normalize divide by max value.

```
import numpy as np
dataset = 10*np.random.rand(4,4,4)      # generate unnormalized array
norm_dataset = dataset/np.max(dataset)  # normalized array
```

Comment: but this way does not only normalize the values along Axis 1