# keras.Normalization column wise

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to add a Normalization layer to my keras model.
And I am testing it in a simpler example, but I don't understand the results.

I did a simple test:

```
normalizer = Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(x_train[:3])
print(x_train[:3])
print(normalizer(x_train[:3]))
```

And I got following results:

```
[[ 82.83  31.04  47.   151.    17.88   0.    58.  ]
 [ 59.71  19.01  50.   141.     6.08   0.    60.  ]
 [133.33  62.68  84.   279.    15.17   0.    65.  ]]
tf.Tensor(
[[-0.2968958  -0.3549137  -0.79461485 -0.62603205  0.95840394  0.
  -1.0190493 ]
 [-1.0490034  -1.0080925  -0.6158265  -0.7851927  -1.3798107   0.
  -0.3396831 ]
 [ 1.3458993   1.3630061   1.4104416   1.411225    0.42140734  0.
   1.3587323 ]], shape=(3, 7), dtype=float32)
```

My question is: if the element in the third row, first column is the maximum of its column, shouldn't it be 1 in the normalized output?

**UPDATE**

It is clear, I was confusing with min_max scale.

Now, I have the issue that if I use adapt with the whole training dataset:

```
normalizer = Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(x_train)
print(x_train[:3])
print(normalizer(x_train[:3]))
```

Then, the second column always gives me nan value:

```
[[ 82.83  31.04  47.   151.    17.88   0.    58.  ]
 [ 59.71  19.01  50.   141.     6.08   0.    60.  ]
 [133.33  62.68  84.   279.    15.17   0.    65.  ]]
tf.Tensor(
[[-0.51946616         nan -1.4330941  -0.5569647   0.8550693  -0.05900022
  -0.17098609]
 [-1.3537331          nan -1.2127512  -0.62386954 -0.8509362  -0.05900022
  -0.1282853 ]
 [ 1.3027862          nan  1.2844696   0.29941723  0.4632664  -0.05900022
  -0.02153332]], shape=(3, 7), dtype=float32)
```

Why that column has nan value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confusing this layer with a min-max scaling. The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization) clearly state that:

> This layer will shift and scale inputs into a distribution centered around 0 with standard deviation 1. It accomplishes this by precomputing the mean and variance of the data, and calling (input - mean) / sqrt(var) at runtime

```py
import tensorflow as tf

normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
x_train = tf.constant([[82.83, 31.04, 47., 151., 17.88, 0., 58.],
                        [59.71, 19.01, 50., 141., 6.08, 0., 60.],
                        [133.33, 62.68, 84., 279., 15.17, 0., 65.]])
normalizer.adapt(x_train)
norm_x = normalizer(x_train)
print(tf.reduce_mean(norm_x), tf.math.reduce_std(norm_x))
```

```
tf.Tensor(6.81196e-08, shape=(), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor(0.9258201, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

With more data, you should come close to mean 0 and std 1. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376478/changing-the-scale-of-a-tensor-in-tensorflow) for min-max scaling.

Comment: Okey, thank you. It is clear now. I have the issue that when I adapt the normalizer with all data that I have the second column is nan. If you, can check the update of the post please.

Comment: It’s hard to say without seeing your whole dataset but I am guessing your dataset has nan values before feeding them to the norm layer